# Example for 1-dim, Noeth., local domain which is unibranched but not analytically irreducible

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Does somebody know an example for an 1-dim., Noeth., local domain $D$ which is unibranched (that is, its integral closure $D'$ is local) but not analytically irreducible (that is, its $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion $\widehat{D}$ is not a domain where  $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of $D$)?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand.  By the Krull-Akizuki theorem, the integral closure $D'$ of $D$ is still Noetherian.  Thus, if $D'$ is local, then it is a Noetherian, local domain that is also integrally closed.  Since $D\subset D'$ is an integral extension, then it satisfies the "incomparability property" so that the dimension of the local ring $D'$ is at most $1$.  As a Noetherian, normal, local domain of dimension $1$, $D'$ is regular.  Thus the completion of $D'$ is also a regular local ring, hence the completion is a domain.

Comment: I think the original post asks if there is an example where $\widehat{D}$ is not a domain not $\widehat{D'}$. In addition to your answer, if $\widehat{D}$ is reduced, then there is a 1-1 correspondence between the maximal ideals of $D'$ and the minimal primes of $\widehat{D}$. Since $D'$ is local, there is unique minimal prime of $\widehat{D}$. Since $\widehat{D}$ is reduced, it is a domain. Therefore, if there is an example, $\widehat{D}$ needs to be non reduced.

Comment: @Youngsu:  Thank you for your clarification.  Since $\widehat{D}$ is $D$-flat, the inclusion $D\hookrightarrow D'$ induces an inclusion $\widehat{D}\hookrightarrow \widehat{D}\otimes_D D'$.  So also, for any example, the induced map $\widehat{D}\otimes_D D' \to \widehat{D'}$ must be noninjective.

Comment: Thank you for the hints and yes Youngsu, that is what I wanted to ask. Also it is known that under the assumptions above, $D$ is analytically irreducible if and only if $D$ is unibranched and $D'$ is finitely generated as $D$-module if and only if $D$ is unibranched and the $\mathfrak{m}'$-adic topologyon $D'$ induces the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology (where $\mathfrak{m}'$ is the maximal ideal of $D'$)

Comment: I found an example (of Akizuki) here [http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9503017v1.pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9503017v1.pdf)